# carbon gates belt drive . need to have lower gears to get up steeper hills. best options

Tags: internally-geared-hub, sprocket

I'm planning to go on a long cycle this year and that last 20k is up a steep incline. I noticed i had to walk up the inclines that were steep and i thought i would have got a lot further if I had one or two lower gears.

I've got a cube travel pro 2020 (https://www.cube.eu/2020/bikes/tour/travel/cube-travel-pro-blacknbrown-2020/). Shimano nexus 8 speed gear hub.

i'm hoping that i can get a smaller front sprocket and larger back sprocket to lower the gearing ratio ? if so please confirm and if you have more knowledge help on my selecting the right combinations so that they will fit the current belt size. youtube installation videos or anything to bring me upto speed.

Another option would be for me to upgrade to an alfine 11 speed hub. I guess that's a solution, it would help if i could sell the 8 speed hub afterwards. https://www.veercycle.com/blogs/getveered/how-to-choose-an-internally-geared-hub

Thanks,
Pat

ravensburg, germany

Comment: For all interested: the bike is described by the Cube site as having 22T on the cassette and 46T on the crankset, with a Gates belt with 120T

Comment: First of all, use the gates calculator to see what sprocket sizes work with your belt. The belt is cheaper than the sprockets and you may find you can get a new front sprocket and belt for not too much. Your existing belt and sprocket will retain some value and can be re-sold depending on condition.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently on the front you can’t go smaller than 46t (you have the 130mm diameter front sprocket).

On the back you can change from 22 to 26t which would make it 18% easier.

It would be in violation of Shimano’s recommendations:

> •The cassette joint should only be used with sprockets with 16T to
> 23T.
>
> •The gear ratio of the front chainring to the rear is about
> 2.1-to-1.

But I think it’s fine, considering that the ratio (and therefore torque at the hub) is still relatively harmless

The lowest gear of the Alfine 11 is <s>7.5% easier</s> not easier than that of the Nexus 8.

Edit: No idea where I had the number from, I now looked up the official specs, the easiest gear is *identical* between Alfine 11 and Nexus 8.
Both have "`Gear ratio_1    0.527`"

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick and great advice/tips. 
Imagine if i installed the alfine 11 at that expense and time effort only to find out it's 7.5% easier than the nexus 8 (i'd be kicking myself and blaming myself for not doing enough research). going to look at getting a 26t . Would i need to change the belt drive as well ?

Comment: So to my mind i can get this 26t sprocket from here for example 
https://www.bike-components.de/de/Gates/CDX-Hintere-Riemenscheibe-3-Lobe-SureFit-Shimano-SRAM-Sturmey-Archer-p62225/
I'm fairly sure i'd need a new belt drive to fit the bigger sprocket. Can somebody confirm this and help me out on odering the right sized and correct belt ? 
this video looks like a start in getting the sprocket replaced. i'd like to do as much as i can myself , i like learning and being independent. bike stores are around if needed of course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgbH22pRAeI

thanks everyone,
Pat

Comment: Sprocket looks good. According to this calculator if you currently have a 22t rear sprocket and 120t belt, increasing to a 26t rear sprocket means you need a 122t belt. Unless you can slacken the tension (i.e. decrease the center-center sprocket distance) of your current belt by 1cm.
https://www.gatescarbondrive.com/~/media/files/gcd/carbon-drive-calculator.xlsx?la=en

Comment: Thanks Michael,
I can't find a cdn 122T (sold out) but have the cdx in the netherlands . I think i'll go for that and it'll handle the strain better when i'm going up steeper hills https://www.pilotonline.store/de/cdx-carbon-drive-belt-122t.html  . That and the cdx sprocket cdx 26T i linked earlier. that should work. just a quick ok back would be great before i pull the trigger. Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks good to me, but I’m no expert on the Gates, I don’t own one, I only find them interesting and follow the development.

Comment: One reads bad things about the CDN (rear sprockets and belt) on the internet, so I think the upgrade to CDX is a good idea.

Comment: the cdx sproket at least seems like a must https://willem.com/blog/2019-02-27_one-year-on-the-ultimate-commuter-bike/ . i'll update when i have the parts and have installed them. I'm very greatful .

Comment: So i've installed the 12T belt drive (cdn, cdx net time ) and cdx 26t rear sprocket. Went for a test drive up a steep hill and the hub started to have a scraping/crunching sound . thought i'd broken the hub. I went to a friendly local german bike shop (a raririty here) and he spotted that i had the gear hub nut the wrong way round which explains how the  gear line slipped on the hardest part of the hill under most pressure and thankfully it wasn't the gear hub giving up the ghost. Also there was a bit of give on the back wheel.

Comment: It was my second time back to him and he's extremly busy but he quickly explained what he meant the first time, flipped the nuts and sent me on my way. I've learned a lot and can do a lot more myself. if i left it to the bike shop, i'd be down a lot of money and knowledge and have to wait two weeks. Everything looking good now. Hopefully i can climb steeper hills this year. thanks everyone